# Missing data - reconstructing large gaps with an autoregressive model

Tags: signal-processing, matlab

I am looking for a similar function as fillgaps in Matlab which helps to "replace missing samples in an otherwise uniformly sampled signal by fitting an autoregressive model to the samples surrounding a gap and extrapolating into the gap from both directions."
https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fillgaps.html

Has anybody already implemented this function in Mathematica? Thanks for your help.